# Execute Shell Script from python and assign output to a variable

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am executing below shell command in python to get the total number of line in a file and was wondering is there any way to assign the output to a variable in python? Thanks

```
import os
cmd = "wc -l" + " " + /path/to/file/text.txt
num_rows = os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: You might want to look into the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `os.exec` class of functions in the `os` module. They are designed to execute the OS-dependent versions of the utils you're referring to. Shell scripts can also be executed in these processes.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-management

You may also want to try the `subprocess` module.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html